# Why doesn't this code put these values inside the spreadsheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl  # pip3 install openpyxl

os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/Weather API')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='SingWeather.xlsx')


def temperature():
    r = requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b02b5107a2c9c27deaa3bc1876bcee81/1.312914,%20103.780257')
    json_object = r.json()
    currently = json_object['currently']

    temperature = currently['temperature']

    apparent = currently['apparentTemperature']


    cloud = currently['cloudCover']
    cloud *= 100
    timenow = datetime.now()
    number = 2
    sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']
    sheet1['A%s' % number] = str(timenow)
    sheet1['B%s' % number] = temperature
    sheet1['C%s' % number] = apparent
    sheet1['D%s' % number] = cloud
    number += 1


while True:
    temperature()
    time.sleep(3597)
```

This code puts nothing in the spreadsheet that is called SingWeather.xlsx. Why does this happen?

I have fixed the grouping problem, but the spreadsheet does nothing.

What are these problems from?

Comment: Regarding the `AttributeError` your regular expressions just didn't match anything. Check what `str(json_object)` actually produces and if it would match.

Comment: I haven't done anything with spreadsheets in python, but do you need to call a save method on `wb`?

Comment: @Michael Ok. I fixed that by changing it to using stuff like `currently = json_object['currently'] and then `temperature = currently['temperature']`, and it works. The spreadsheet does nothing though.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I am an idiot. I forgot to save the spreadsheet using `wb.save('SingWeather.xlsx')` at the end of my editing. Fixed.